# Create Table Layout in android

Tags: android, listview, android-tablelayout

I want to create table Layout using Listview.But the no of rows and columns are dynamically generated. So how can i create ?

for eg.) If row =2 cols=2 means list view automatically create 2 rows and 2 cols

If row =3 cols =4 means listview create 3 rows and 4 cols automatically

So what i understand is i want to create 2 listview (1 for row and other for cols) is it right ? can anyone share the sample code?

i choose listview because of the table shows with scroll bar

But my table only contains textview .

Comment: you can use recyclerview instead.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow is the library which will help you get table view type of view

https://github.com/jondoes/TableView

Comment: Sorry without using any libraries i want to create a table with no of rows & cols (contains textview only with scroll bar horizondal and vertical)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) or [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) and set number of columns programmatically.

Comment: i am not familiar with grid view can u pls share the code which contains textview table with no of rows & cols using listview (scroll bar horizondal & vertical)